# R tutorial for multitask regression tree for missing value prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, r

I have a dataframe with 20 columns. Data is integrated from five different data sources. I have shown 4 columns from each dataset. 4/5 sources have discrete data (either 1 or 0). The last section has continuous values which is my target (Contains NA). I intend to implement Random Forest algorithm to predict the missing values. I have seen tutorials which predict only one Y variable. Is this a regression tree for missing value prediction task for continuous multioutput Y? kindly share some tutorial links which could provide some reference code in R.

> Input File Sample

```
  D000022 D000038 D000152 D000163 A01AB06 A01AB07 A01AB08 A01AB09 76 77 80 84 fp131 fp132 fp133 fp134 C0000727 C0000731 C0000737 C0000768
1       1       0       0       1       0       1       0       0  1  0  1  0     0     1     0     1     0.03       0    0.0406    0.26
2       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0  0  1  0  1     1     1     0     0       NA       NA      NA     NA
3       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  1  0  1  0     0     1     1     0        1        0   0.1900    0.3
```

Comment: Do you want to predict the expected value of the instances with NA, or use them for learning? If it is the latter, I would exclude them as unclassified.

Comment: @CalZ So, If there is NA in Y, It means I do not have a ground truth and It is not included in the training set, hence not in cross-validation set up ?

Comment: Yes, I would exclude those then. They *might* be interesting to include in a testing or validation set later on to see if you can generate a label for them.

Comment: @CalZ I have seen tutorials that predict just one Y column variable, kindly suggest a tutorial for multivariate target prediction.

Comment: Why not run several single target regressions?

Comment: @CalZ You mean to say loop over the Y targets one by one?

Comment: ifran - Correct.

Comment: @CalZ Thank you. If you could also add a reference tutorial. I shall be grateful.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on building a linear model using caret in R: http://sharpsightlabs.com/blog/quick-introduction-machine-learning-r-caret/

Comment: @CalZ Kindly suggest R tutorial for multi-tasking regression tree.

Comment: How about just running multiple regressions in a row? For example, run it once predicting the first target, then repeat for each additional. If you wanted to get fancy, you could index your target variables and put it in a for loop :)

Comment: @CalZ I donot want to solve it as single task. I want a multitask R tutorial